# Wordpress Developer Custom Background Options

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been reading the WordPress codex on adding custom background options, like in this example

```php
$defaults = array(
    'default-color'          => '',
    'default-image'          => '',
    'default-repeat'         => '',
    'default-position-x'     => '',
    'default-attachment'     => '',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
```

The generated output then looks exactly like this:

```html
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #bdd96e; }
</style>
```

This won't work because of the complexity of my theme, i need to be able to change the above snippet so it will override the default background for .menu-wrapper tag, is there a way I can change the default CSS selector to target a different tag instead of body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in the callback function `_custom_background_cb`? Is that part of core WP?

I'm completely guessing here but I think you'll want to define a function that is called to return the output you want. You'll need to adjust for  `admin-head-callback`, & `admin-preview-callback` too.

Try something like this but you might need to do some research on the callback parameters.

```
$defaults = array(
//  ...
  'wp-head-callback' => 'my_custom_function',
//  ...

);
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );

function my_custom_function()
{
    $html =  "<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">";
    $html += "   #my-selector { background-color: #bdd96e; }";
    $html += "</style>";
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a lot! c: